# Cannot "git clone" from local host

Tags: git, ssh

Two laptops with ubuntu installed.

ssh and git config for user1 on these systems are identical settings.

```
cat /home/user1/.ssh/config
Host system1
        Hostname <system1_ip>
        User user1
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_common

cat /home/user1/.gitconfig
[user]
        email = user1@gmail.com
        name = user1
```

Rsa private/public key are also the same in these systems

```
user1@system1:~/.ssh$ ls -al
total 28
drwx------  2 user1 user1 4096 Apr 18 00:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 50 user1 user1 4096 Apr 18 00:06 ..
-rw-------  1 user1 user1  408 Feb 18  2017 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r--  1 user1 user1   91 Apr 18 00:04 config
-r--------  1 user1 user1 1675 Feb 24  2017 id_rsa_common
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1  408 Feb 24  2017 id_rsa_common.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1 1550 Apr 12 19:51 known_hosts


user1@system2:~/.ssh$ ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxr-x  2 user1 user1 4096 Apr 17 20:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 user1 user1 4096 Apr 17 23:08 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user1 user1   91 Apr 17 20:12 config
-r--------  1 user1 user1 1675 Apr 17 20:12 id_rsa_common
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1  408 Apr 17 20:12 id_rsa_common.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 user1 1550 Apr 17 20:12 known_hosts
```

A git repository created in system1.

user1@system2 can do "git clone" properly

```
user1@system2:~/job/test$ git clone ssh://<system1_ip>/home/git_root/mypicture.git
Cloning into 'mypicture'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
orion@ubuntu-pavilion:~/job/test$ ls -al mypicture/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 user1 user1 4096 Apr 18 01:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 user1 user1 4096 Apr 18 01:38 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 user1 user1 4096 Apr 18 01:38 .git
```

user1@system1 try to "git clone"

The response is Permission denied (publickey).

```
user1@system1:~/job/git_test/local/temp$ git clone ssh://<system1_ip>/home/git_root/mypicture.git
Cloning into 'mypicture'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Debug with this command:

GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone ssh://system1_ip/home/git_root/mypicture.git

Part of dump shows it cannot find the private key:

```
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
....
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
```

How to change ssh/git config or someghing else for user1@system1 to "git clone" this repository on system1?

Comment: What are the permissions on the `.ssh` directories?

Comment: `0700` and `0775` resp. apparently. That is actually included in the question. In that sense it's the system2 I would expect to see problem. The `config` perms might be too much too though.

Answer (score 2):

I would venture a guess that too permissive `${HOME}/.ssh/config` is tripping your ssh, try restricting it to `0600`. Looking at the verbose output, it tries the default names of keys and not `~/.ssh/id_rsa_common` You've specified.

You may also correct the permission on your system two. Usually `$HOME/.ssh/` would be `0700` and `config` and keys as well as `known_hosts` and `authorized_hosts` would be `0600`.

However, it's just a guess based on the available info. And one thing stomps me (but could be *buntu specific), my `ssh` would reject `${HOME}/.ssh/config` with permbits as seen on your system, but it would also let me know it did so on the console with `Bad owner or permissions on /home/user1/.ssh/config`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

#### Add the key to the ssh:

```
ssh-add
```

This will add the default key unless you provide the specific key you wish to add

> `ssh-add` is a command for adding SSH private keys into the SSH authentication agent for implementing single sign-on with SSH. The agent process is called `ssh-agent`
>
> read below see how to run it.

#### Start/restart the ssh=agent

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

This will start the ssh agent and will print out the PID of the servive.

> The `ssh-agent` is a **helper** program that keeps track of user's identity keys and their passphrases. The agent can then use the keys to log into other servers without having the user type in a password or passphrase again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!

eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_common
 

I guess the user1@system1 will use this key for any ssh remotes.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is user1@system1 cannot recognize `ssh://system1_ip` while executing `git clone`.

`${HOME}/.ssh/config` only specify the key in `Host system1` not `Host system1_ip`

So it works properly if user1@system1 to apply `ssh://system1`

BUT so far I have no idea why user1@system2 can specify the key if `ssh://system1_ip` .